# How to provide the TCache type when creating a new instance of ApolloClient?

Tags: typescript, apollo, apollo-client

I have the following code:

```
const client: ApolloClient<any> = new ApolloClient({
  uri: MY_URI,
});
```

And I'd like to replace `any` with a `TCache` type, as indicated by the VSCode tooltip that pops up when I remove `any`:

[image: VSCode Tooltip]

The issue is that `TCache` cannot be imported from `apollo-client`:

```
import { TCache } from "apollo-client"; // does NOT work
```

I also cloned their [repo](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client) and tried to find a definition for `TCache`, but there's none.

Comment: Hey @Paul did you find a solution for your issue?

Comment: Nope. I only recall that they recommended not using the types here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you would provide a cache option to the client and then provide the "cache shape" for that type. You can see this by looking at the types for `ApolloClient`:

```js
export declare type ApolloClientOptions<TCacheShape> = {
    …
    cache: ApolloCache<TCacheShape>;
    …
};
```

For the built-in `InMemoryCache`, looking at the code yields its shape is `NormalizedCacheObject`:

```js
export declare class InMemoryCache extends ApolloCache<NormalizedCacheObject> {
    …
}
```

So your code would become:

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, NormalizedCacheObject} from "@apollo/client";

const client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  uri: MY_URI,
});
```